# How get the href of each class and store it inside a list (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a list I have with 7 entries. On the picture below you can see the area which I marked purple: 6 entries. You see the area which I marked blue, all the 7 entries got the same `<a class` "FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z".
My question is how can I get the href of each entry and store them all in a list/array? In this example, the href of first entry is `/foo.96/`.

If my question is not clear please tell me and I will try to describe it differently! :)

[image]

Comment: just `[...document.querySelectorAll('a.FPmhX.notranslate.MBL3Z')].map(e=>e.href)` ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) [Please don't post images of code.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of StackOverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create parent element of list in html and in your javascript write:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a.FPmhX.notranslate.MBL3Z");
var list = document.querySelector("ul#linkList");///Your path to parent

for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    list.innerHTML += "<li>" + links[i].href + "</li>";
}
```

Or if you want to get the pathname then use `links[i].pathname` instead of `links[i].href`.

Here's the snippet

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a.FPmhX.notranslate.MBL3Z");
var list = document.querySelector("ul#linkList");

for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    list.innerHTML += "<li>" + links[i].href + "</li>";
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" class="FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z"></a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/" class="FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z"></a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions" class="FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z"></a>
<a href="https://css-tricks.com/" class="FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z"></a>
<ul id="linkList">
  Links:
</ul>
```

Is it helpful? :)